# Devise custom failure root for sign up preserving errors

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, devise

I am building an app which uses the homepage at `home#index` for both sign in and sign up.

I have managed to get devise to redirect to home on failure to sign in using a custom failure app class, and error messages are passed in `flash[:alert]`

Now I am trying to redirect to home when the user fails to SIGN UP. I have been able to get it to redirect to home by using a custom registration controller and

```
redirect_to root_path
```

however as the errors are attached to `resource` and this isn't preserved I can't display the validation errors.

I have tried

```
respond_with resource, location: root_path
```

and this doesn't work

Comment: `flash` will not be present on a redirect, use render instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Comment by Surya was correct. I changed the `respond_with` to

```
render 'home/index'
```

No more need for flash for the errors as the resource persists for the render. Only annoying thing now is that it changes the path to ".../user" rather than "/" but its just an annoyance.